java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError caused by executable
I have downloaded a Linux executable for the program CircuitSim.  You can see the downloads here:
https://www.roiatalla.com/public/CircuitSim/
I downloaded the version 1.6.2, hoping that I wouldn't have problems with needing a newer version of Java.
My current version of Java is
$ java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.23" 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.23+9-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)

I've marked the downloaded executable as an executable program, and then in a terminal ran ./CircuitSim1.6.2.
The response it gives is
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ra4king.circuitsim.gui.CircuitSim
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

I'm guessing this has something to do with this post: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
But I don't understand pretty much anything that's being said there, I'm not familiar with Java EE.  But my guess is that the solutions there are relevant for when you're calling on the Java compiler directly.  Here, if I understand my situation a little, I'm calling an executable that's calling the compiler -- so I think I can't use the solution there?  I dunno.
Any help on how to run this program would be appreciated.

Alternative approach: What happens if you download the latest JAR and then (from within the directory where the JAR file is located), run java -jar CircuitSim[yourversion].jar? Apart from that, I wonder if this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

The question seems to be about support for an application rather than a programming question. As such is off topic.

You should direct support questions to the publisher of that software.  (He's easy to identify, and he even provided a contact email address.)  If you were asking this because you are trying to learn how to write and run Java programs, there are a myriad of resources on how to do that.

Root cause:
You have not installed and configured the JavaFX SDK.
The easiest way:
install a JDK that already integrates JavaFX.
Installed via SDKMAN The JDK including JavaFX has been integrated.
You can use sdk list java and then look for files with xxx.fx.xxx in the name to select an installation. You can find fx in the name.
sdk install java 21.0.3.fx-zulu

After the installation is complete, execute the following instructions:
./CircuitSim1.6.2



firstly,you can try again reload this jar,may you can maven clean let u know the local source not error; if error again after you done,try to read demo for javafx such as https://gitee.com/westinyang/javafx-jdk11-start, if always error again~ i guess maybe java compiler hadn't choose the right classloader,u can try update your local jdk version,such as jdk 8;
